# Disable animation on scaling/rotation with transform

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm making a chess game in a page and I'm trying to flip the whole board (a div) using the css transform. I first tried rotate or scale(1, -1) both are working but makes a small annoying animation.

[image: Rotate]

What I want is to get rid of this animation. CSS code of the class I'm dynamically adding and removing to my divs:

```
.rotated {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);  /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
    transform: rotate(180deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

I am not looking for `transition-delay`, transforms and transitions aren't the same thing. Setting `transition-delay` to 0ms (default value) didn't change anything.

Comment: Make jsfiddle.net, please!

Comment: Hi, so you want the board to rotate but not the chess pieces, correct?

Comment: @Sohaib Mohammed was doing it until someone came with an answer so I will do it only if needed.

Comment: Nick_O exact but since the board makes the pieces rotate, I need to rotate both and that makes the bad animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your HTML code, but if you are only adding the .rotated class to the main div - you must also add this class to the individual chess piece divs.

For example, if you were using jQuery to add the class ...it would look something like this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#container").toggleClass("rotated");
  $("div.white").toggleClass("rotated");
  $("div.black").toggleClass("rotated");
});
```

```css
.chessboard {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 25px solid #333;
}
.black {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #999;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.white {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.rotated {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle Board</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="chessboard" class="chessboard">
    <!-- 1st -->
    <div class="white">&#9820;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9822;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9821;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9819;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9818;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9821;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9822;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9820;</div>
    <!-- 2nd -->
    <div class="black">&#9821;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9821;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9821;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9821;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9821;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9821;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9821;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9821;</div>
    <!-- 3th -->
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!-- 4st -->
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <!-- 5th -->
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!-- 6th -->
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <!-- 7th -->
    <div class="white">&#9817;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9817;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9817;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9817;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9817;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9817;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9817;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9817;</div>
    <!-- 8th -->
    <div class="black">&#9814;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9816;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9815;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9813;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9812;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9815;</div>
    <div class="black">&#9816;</div>
    <div class="white">&#9814;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hmmvrw7r/)

Comment: I'm also adding the class to the pieces but they are animated. But thanks for your example I'll try to figure out why yours isn't animated and come back.

Comment: Sorry, my html is created on run time from a custom grid widget but it looks like this. Anyway, the important point is how to stop the css animation, I will give a better short example if needed.

Comment: Oh I see, the reason why your pieces don't rotate in your example is because you use characters for them while I use background images. I've should mentionned it, sorry.

Comment: Well I fixed my problem by transforming a parent div instead of the child but since you gave me a working example, I will accept your answer.